# How to make <exec "cp" exclude .svn files in ANT?

Tags: unix, ant, cp

I have this ant talk to copy cgi-dir to cgi-dest.

```
    <exec executable="cp" failonerror="yes">
        <arg value="-a" />
        <arg value="${cgi-dir}" />
        <arg value="${cgi-dest}" />
    </exec>
```

I chose this method over the "copy" ant task because I wanted to preserve permissions.  The ant task explicitly can't.

The problem is that it copies all the .svn directories it sees, how can I prevent this?

Comment: Isn't it `-p` for permissions? `-a` means all, and finds all file/dirs, even thous beginning with `.`. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, but I meant permissions as the reason im using <exec> instead of <copy>

Comment: my point is that the `-a` option (at least for a typical linux/unix system) is designed to find files like `.svn*`. Do you think that the `ant cp` task is designed to function differently? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.. you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839596/how-can-i-exclude-files-from-a-reference-path-in-ant), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585929/how-to-use-cp-command-to-exclude-a-specific-directory) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808413/how-can-i-exclude-a-list-of-files-held-in-a-file-from-an-ant-fileset) .

This will work I think: `tar --exclude='.svn' -c -f - /path/to/sourcedir/* | (cd /path/to/destdir ; tar xfp -)`

PS : These existing answers automatically appear as suggestions on the right hand side under **"Related"** and also when you are typing the subject to your question (it appears you are new to Stack Exchange).

Nevertheless, good luck.

Comment: Yes, but none of these deal with <exec ... "cp", which strangely includes .svn whereas the manpage for unix cp explicitly excludes it.

Comment: @JD. I understand your situation now. Options  -
1. Use a Unix trick like `tar --exclude='.svn' -c -f - /path/to/sourcedir/* | (cd /path/to/destdir ; tar xfp -)` where you create a temp TAR without specific files and then UNTAR it to the destination

2. Use a inefficient two step process with first using CP and then delete .svn (I am sure you have already thought about this)

3.From here [link] (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/copy-svn-working-dir-without-svn-hidden-dirs-and-files-620586/) rsync -r --exclude=.svn /home/user/progname/ /home/user/progname.copy

Comment: One more : Use `DOS XCOPY` from within `exec` with `/EXCLUDE /O/K`

Comment: @JD did this solve your problem. If yes, can you please mark this as the correct answer :)